# Can you send background notifications on mobile with Bootstrap or jQuery Mobile?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile

For example when someone likes your comment on fb and your mobile is in sleep mode, it can receive notifications. And when you are using your mobile and  the fb app is in the background it sends notifications too. I wonder if that can be achieved with any of those technologies described above? If the answer is no, do you know if it can be achieved with Phonegap?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve,you can check `Push Notifications` for your requirement.

Comment: its possible with Jquery! but with permission from the browser

Comment: @Zeeshan Thank you for your answer. Yes I want Push Notifications. Can you achieve that with Bootstrap or jQuery Mobile?

Comment: For web you need use `Web Push` and for Android App you need to use `GCM Push` and for IOS apps `APN Push`